# How to transform all strings to numbers in a nested array, except actual strings in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel-addins

I am trying to transform all values in a 2D array from strings to numbers, except values that are actually strings (within the Javascript Excel Add-in API)

Example:

```
[["1000"],["3.2"],["banana"]]
```

to

```
[[1000],[3.2],["banana]]

"1000" -> 1000
"3.2" -> 3.2
"banana" -> "banana"
```

Comment: `isNaN(parseFloat(YOUR_STRING))` will help you check if a string can be parsed to a number or not

Comment: did you checked for parseInt()

Comment: Thank you @Terry ! I will do an if statement using that, and apply Number(str) if it passes that test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will help you solve the problem:

```
var values = ['1000','3.2','banana'];

function stringToNumber(arrayOfValues) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfValues.length; i++) {
    if (typeof arrayOfValues[i] != 'string' || isNaN(arrayOfValues[i])) {
      continue;
    }
    arrayOfValues[i] = +arrayOfValues[i];  // + before a string converts it to number
  }
}
```

---

Update:

In the comment below, you wrote you receive a nested array from Excel, so I wrote a recursive function for you:

```
var arrayOfArrays = [
  ['1000','3.2','banana'], 
  ['2','value','1820','just a word', true], 
  [20]
]; 

var values = ['1000','3.2','banana']; 

function stringToNumber(arrayOfValues) { 
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfValues.length; i++) { 
    if (typeof arrayOfValues[i] == 'object') {
      stringToNumber(arrayOfValues[i]); continue;
    }
    if (typeof arrayOfValues[i] != 'string' || isNaN(arrayOfValues[i])) {
      continue;
    }
    arrayOfValues[i] = +arrayOfValues[i]; // + before a string converts it to number
  }
}
```

Try it out!

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work because I'm working with an array of arrays. An excel table of this format
`line1 -> 1   2   3; 
line2 -> 4   5   6;  
line3 -> 7   8   9`
returns

`[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

Comment: Just loop through the array of arrays to make it work. You might want to use recursion if you do not know the depth of the nested array. The principle described in the code above will work here.

Comment: @FranciscoBarroca , I updated my response and added a recursive function for you to handle nested arrays. Good luck!

Comment: Hello @Fillyjonk ! Thank you so much! I don't know why but I tried your code and I did console.log(stringToNumber(arrayOfArrays)); and it returns "Undefined)

Comment: @FranciscoBarroca , this is because the function is a void function, i.e. it does not return anything, it only modifies your existing array. The following works:
1) stringToNumber(arrayOfArrays); 2) stringToNumber(values); 3) console.log(arrayOfArrays); 4) console.log(values);

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper function where you use your own rules to determine whether a string is a number or not:

```js
function asNumberIfPossible (str) {
  if (str === '') return str;
  const n = Number(str);
  return Number.isNaN(n) ? str : n;
}

const examples = [
  '1000',
  '3.2',
  'banana',
  '0',
  '',
  '1.2e5',
  '0xfff',
  '0b101',
  ' 0',
  '0 ',
  '0 1',
  '15px',
  '28.5px',
];

for (const str of examples) {
  const result = asNumberIfPossible(str);
  console.log(
    typeof result,
    JSON.stringify(str),
    '->',
    JSON.stringify(result),
  );
}
```

Note that using the [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number) constructor to coerce strings is more strict than using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). When using `parseFloat()`, for example, the string `"28.5px"` becomes the number `28.5`, but using the `Number()` constructor to coerce the string will result in `NaN`. This strictness is desirable in my opinion because it prevents a loss of information during the coercion:

```js
const str = '28.5px';

console.log('parseFloat:', parseFloat(str));
console.log('Number:', Number(str));
```

Comment: Thank you! In this case, the only rule would be: if it includes any letters from the alphabet, it's a string

Answer (score 0):

Just use the unary plus operator. Any string can be turned into a number using it, as long as the string is *exclusively* a number.

```
var x = +”1000”; // results in 1000
var y = +”Hi” // NaN
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check if the value is greater than -1 and Math.abs to convert the negative to positive, if the condition is true then the value is a number, and if not it's a string.

```js
if(Math.abs(value) > -1) {
    // value is a number
  } else {
    // value is not a number
  }
```

Comment: Your code gives false negative for zero.